# How to use BulkOutputFormat to stream the data to the Cassandra from Hadoop Map function?

Tags: streaming, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

1) I have the row-key, column and value in Map of Hadoop Job and I came to know that I can stream this directly to Cassandra using **BulkOutputFormat**.

2) I have gone through the code but it is quite difficult to understand how to use it.
How can I use this BulkOutputFormat API to stream the data to Cassandra?

As the more documentation is not yet available on this I request the Cassandra Experts to guide me through this.
 A small code snippet would be very helpful.
I am planning to test it with current development version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into cassandra source code and cassandra JIRA I have figured out the way to use BulkOutputFormat and described it here:[Using BulkOutputFormat to load data to cassandra with Hadoop](http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.com/2012/03/bulkloadto-cassandra-with-hadoop.html)